# 'Rules' to be taken into account when working with cross-domain iframe content

Tags: iframe, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

Originally, I was planning on a site that would've involved the manipulation of any elements loaded into an iframe from another domain. I now know that's not possible because of the policy around the origin of it, what other policies are in place that I need to take into account?

I'm asking because although I'm no longer going to attempt to access the iframe contents, I am still going to rely on the iframe as a major source of my site's content and it will, in fact, span the majority of the screen space. Users will be able to navigate to certain sites using the iframe. Is there anything I've got to comply with while doing this? Are there restrictions in the way I use other sites' content?

May seem kind of like the more non-technical kind of topic but I'd rather confirm this prior to spending months of dev work on it.

Comment: What language are you using for the sever side programming? If you use php, you should have a look at `readfile()` http://scottbush.net/web-dev/goodbye-iframes-hello-php-readfile/

Comment: I'm using .net, and I appreciate there are probably viable workarounds such as a proxy, but I'm more concerned by what I have to avoid doing when i have the content. Thanks.